# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**class Login as the following method Kreato_Login():-**

```
public void Kreato_Login(){
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "https://testrugtn.kreatocrm.com/";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit. SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
        driver.findElement(By. id("Login_txtUserName")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By. id("Login_txtUserName")).sendKeys( "saravana");
        driver.findElement(By. id("Login_txtPassword")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By. id("Login_txtPassword")).sendKeys( "5678");
        driver.findElement(By. id("Login_btnLogin")).click();

}
```

**Class Lead as the following method "Lead_MandatoryCheck()":-**

```
LoginLogout leadInstance=new LoginLogout();
public void Lead_MandatoryCheck() throws InterruptedException{
    leadInstance.Kreato_Login();
    driver1.findElement(By. xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Customers')]")).click();
    driver1.findElement(By. linkText("Leads")).click();
    //Add New
    driver1.findElement(By. cssSelector( "#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cbpSubContent_imgAddNew_CD > span.dx-vam" )).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    //Save
    driver1.findElement(By. cssSelector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cbpAssociationNew_btnNewItemTopCreationSave_CD > span.dx-vam" )).click();
    String mandatoryPopup= driver1.switchTo().alert().getText();
    driver1.switchTo().alert().accept();
    System.out.println(mandatoryPopup);

}
```

**I try to call the above methods from the class Trigger as follows:-**

```
public class TriggerClass {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*LeadCreation lc= new LeadCreation();
        lc.setUp();
        lc.testLeadCreation();
        lc.tearDown();*/
    LeadModule Lm=new LeadModule();
    Lm.Lead_MandatoryCheck();
}
```

when i run the "Trigger.class"

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at workflow.LeadModule.Lead_MandatoryCheck(LeadModule.java:132)
at workflow.TriggerClass.main(TriggerClass.java:13)
```

Comment: are you using 2 different instances of webdriver? driver and driver1?

Comment: What is type of variable "BaseURL"?

Comment: LoginLogout leadInstance=new LoginLogout(); What is the defination for the LoginLogout class ?

Comment: @HelpingHands BaseURL is a string. (public String BaseURL;)

Comment: @RupeshShinde LoginLogout is class in which i have two methods {Kreato_Login} & {Kreato_Logout} for login and to logout.

Comment: @pArAs i have created two instance for two class. {driver & driver1}. i dont know how to use the instance/variables from one class to other class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should structure your class, members and functions:

**TriggerClass.java:**

```
public class TriggerClass {

public static WebDriver driver;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    LeadModule Lm=new LeadModule();
    Lm.Lead_MandatoryCheck();
}
```

**LeadModule.java:**

```
public class LeadModule {

     public WebDriver driver;

     public LeadModule() {
        this.driver = TriggerClass.driver;
     }

    public void Lead_MandatoryCheck() throws InterruptedException{
        LoginLogout leadInstance = new LoginLogout();
        leadInstance.Kreato_Login();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Customers')]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Leads")).click();
        //Add New
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector( "#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cbpSubContent_imgAddNew_CD > span.dx-vam" )).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        //Save
        driver.findElement(By. cssSelector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cbpAssociationNew_btnNewItemTopCreationSave_CD > span.dx-vam" )).click();
        String mandatoryPopup= driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
        System.out.println(mandatoryPopup);

    }
```

**LoginLogout.java:**

```
public class LoginLogout extends LeadModule {

public void Kreato_Login(){
        baseUrl = "https://testrugtn.kreatocrm.com/";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit. SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Login_txtUserName")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("Login_txtUserName")).sendKeys("saravana");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Login_txtPassword")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("Login_txtPassword")).sendKeys("5678");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Login_btnLogin")).click();

}

}
```

Your Java/Selenium basics are not clear. Please read through the documentation or view related tutorials on YouTube.

Comment: i tried the above code and i run. but it says "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at workflow.LoginLogout.<init>(LoginLogout.java:8)
 at workflow.LeadModule.<init>(LeadModule.java:14)
"

Comment: StackOverflow..haha..what a coincidence. BTW, updated the code in LeadModule() constructor. Moved the LoginLogout class object declaration to Lead_Mandatory_Check() method.